# return object models in array with PHPStan

Tags: php, phpstan

Lets say you have 3 models like this

```
class User extends AbstractModel {
     protected string $name = 'User';
} 

class Car extends AbstractModel {
     protected int $weels = 4;
} 

class House extends AbstractModel {
     protected string $address = 'Some Street 26a';
}
```

then you have a fuctions that returns the 3 models like this

```
protected function generateModels(): array
{
     $user  = new User();
     $car   = new Car();
     $house = new House();

     return [$user, $car, $house]
}
```

then you have some tests like this

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public fuction this_is_some_random_test(): void
{
     [
         $user,
         $car,
         $house,
     ] = $this->generateModels();

     $user->name;
     $address->weels;
     $house->address;

     $result1 = some_function_require_user_model($user);

     //some assertions
}
```

So how do you need to typehint the functions `generateModels()` that PHPstan understands that It can be multiple models? cause `array<int, mixed>` doesnt works `array<int, AbstractModel>` also not cause it will complain like `property $name doesnt exist on AbstractModel` and the third is like `array<int, User|Car|House>` what also doenst seem the works cause you will get the same errors and then the functions says that the `Car|House` types are now allowed. So how can I type hint it propperly?

PHPStan level 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a method returns `array<int,User|Car|House>` it means that the method returns an array of instances of those classes. According to this annotation you can get `[User,Car]`, `[Car,House]` or just `[Car,Car,Car]` (or any other combination). This is why PHPStan complains about this: it's trying to tell you that there might be possible error in the future. Although you (as an author) know that the first position contains `User` at this moment, the code doesn't know it so it assumes that the first position might not be `User` but also `Car` or `House` which don't contain property `$name` as `User` does. For avoiding this possible error **you can use `instanceof` for checking the class**. If you use `$res[0] instanceof User` PHPStan (and the code itself) will know that the first item in array is an instance of `User` meaning you can get the `$name` property without any worry.

```php
$res = $this->generateModels(); // $res is array<User|Car|House>

$item1 = $res[0]; // $item1 is User|Car|House

echo $item1->name; // Error: name has only User (but $item1 is User, Car or House)

if ($item1 instanceof User) {
    echo $item1->name; // OK: The code knows $item1 is 100% User
}
```

*But* if you know the order of the types inside the array (e.g. first is `User`, second is `Car` and last is `House`), you can **use [array shapes](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#array-shapes)** for speciffying types of individual keys.

```php
class ModelGenerator
{
    /**
     * @return array{0: User, 1: Car, 2: House}
     */
    protected function generateModels(): array
    {
         $user  = new User();
         $car   = new Car();
         $house = new House();
    
         return [$user, $car, $house]
    }
}
```